# import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\zampliasurveys_frontend\node_modules\react-toastify\dist\ReactToastify.css:1
({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){:root {
^

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

   6 | import { Footer } from "components/Footer/Footer";
   7 | import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
>  8 | import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
     | ^
   9 |
  10 | export const Layout = () => {
  11 |   return (

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/Layout/index.tsx:8:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/AppRoutes.tsx:9:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.tsx:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/__test__/App.test.tsx:3:1)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just need to add the foolowing configuration in package.json, below dev dependencies.

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(axios|react-toastify))"
],
```

//This the way how you can make eslint ignore syntax related to a dependency

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have installed all dependencies..
run after doing

> npm install

in terminal